# Update same table as selected with calculated values using resultset

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I'm new to sql (scripting). Single CRUD commands are no problem, but I'm trying to create a stored procedure that wil update a table with a calculated value using the results from the same selected table.

In the table there is a value with the total vacation-hours for each employee and a value of the remainder of the vaction-hours of the last year.

What I will try to achieve is to ADD the new hours for this year to the remaining hours. There is one catch. The new hours column is in whole hours, the remaining-hours is a value in 'ticks' which is hundred nanoseconds.

How can I update the table using the same table as a reference for this calculation?

```
example table:
employee, vacation, remainingvacation

new value of remainigvacation = vacation(in hours) * 60(minutes) * 60(seconds) * 10^9 (to convert to ticks) + remainingvacation (in ticks)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE
  myTable
SET
  remainingvacation = (vacation * 60 * 60 * POWER(10, 9)) + remainingvacation
```

You can then do the same after including JOINS and WHERE clauses...

```
UPDATE
  myTable
SET
  remainingvacation = (vacation * 60 * 60 * POWER(10, 9)) + remainingvacation
FROM
  myTable
INNER JOIN
  yourTable
    ON myTable.id = yourTable.id
WHERE
  yourTable.value = 'Egyptian Holidays'
```

Comment: Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int. 

This happens while the remainingvacation column is of type bigint

Comment: when deleting the power function and using a normal number al goes well.

Comment: @LuukKrijnen: Replace `vacation` with `CAST(vacation AS bigint)` or any of the `60`s with `CAST(60 AS bigint)`.

Comment: @LuukKrijnen - Or just use `* CAST(3600000000000 AS BIGINT)` [As far as I know, it will default to DECIMAL for large numbers, unless specifically CAST]

Comment: this is not working in postgresql. You must do it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393706/postgresql-update-using-aggregate-function

Answer (score -1):

Why would you store and process "vacation hours":

- once in integers
- once in NANOSECONDS?

You should use the same units for data type TIME - either days, or hours, or even those nanoseconds, in all places where you consume TIME in related processes.

Consistency across the database is a must, don't introduce unnecessary units and data types. Even using just seconds would suffice.

Comment: Do you think that your post can be described as an answer/solution to the question/problem at the top of this page? Then please [edit] to make it more obvious to OP. Even if your observations are applicable, this is more of a comment. For that you need to understand https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead and generally you really should take the [tour] and read [answer].