# PostgreSQL: UPDATE using aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I want to update the table `paneldata` setting the column `ibase` using an aggregate function.

```
UPDATE paneldata p
SET ibase=SUM(1/i.dist)
FROM ibaselang i
WHERE p.gid=i.gid
AND i.instp<p.period
```

This results in `ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in UPDATE`

### TABLE DEFINITIONS

```
CREATE TABLE public.ibaselang
(
  gid integer,
  dist double precision,
  buildid integer,
  instp smallint
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

### Solution Approach

Unfortunately I don't know how to implement my `WHERE` functions in a subquery.

Answer (score 24):

Here's a generic example of how to do it.

```
UPDATE public.customer_value cv
SET total_value = sub_q.sum_val 
FROM 
    (
    SELECT SUM(order_amount) AS sum_val, o.customer_id 
    FROM public.orders AS o
    GROUP BY o.customer_id
    ) AS sub_q
WHERE sub_q.customer_id = cv.customer_id;
```

If you want to try this example out in full you can create the dummy data like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.customer_value
(
  customer_id int 
, total_value numeric (10,2)
);

CREATE TABLE public.orders 
(
  customer_id int
, order_amount numeric(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO public.customer_value
(customer_id)
VALUES 
  (1)
, (2);


INSERT INTO public.orders
(customer_id, order_amount)
VALUES 
 (1, 10)
,(1, 10)
,(2, 7.5)
,(2, 7.5);
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know how efficient this is, but it should work:

```
with updates as (
  select
    p.gid, sum (i.dist) as dist
  from
    paneldata p
    join ibaselang i on
      p.id = i.gid and
      i.instp < p.period
  where
    i.dist != 0
  group by
    p.gid
)
update paneldata p
set
  ibase = 1 / u.dist
from
  updates u
where
  p.gid = u.pid and
  u.dist != 0
```

A couple of other notes about additions:

1. If your `i.dist` has a lot of zeroes, removing the zero values in the `where` clause could theoretically speed up your query
2. You have a potential vulnerability for a divide by zero error -- that is also handled in the update statement.  Maybe your data doesn't have this condition, but it's best to handle it to be sure

Answer (score 4):

Try using a correlated query like this:

```
UPDATE paneldata p
SET p.ibase=(select SUM(1/i.dist)
             FROM ibaselang i
             WHERE p.gid=i.gid
             AND i.instp<p.period)
```

Comment: But that will update all lines!! , where condition must be respected?